# Region + Region = Region

Tags: geography, crosswords

> Solve the crossword then find the final answer by the answers you got.
> [image]

Clues:

> Across
>
> > 2. The Big Dipper is so beautiful at night.
> > 3. Why is that man killing a demon!?
> > 4. That lion is posing with a sword.
> > 5. A fox just found some gold.
> > 6. Russia but surrounded but yellow.

> Down
>
> > 1. [Word 9] but different
> > 2. That dog is shy.
> > 3. Have you ever heard of an inuksuk?
> > 4. I see an aurora.
> > 5. Solve the puzzle of Poland.
> > 6. 8 fish tails with some if you look closer.
> > 7. Snowy summer.

The number order is by the most northern letter

Comment: Would it damage the puzzle to give a textual transcription of the clues? They're a tad tiny and blurry, even to a person with decent eyesight

Comment: @bobble Can't they just click the image and make it in fullscreen? But okay.

Comment: I will just do a high quality version. Is that okay?

Comment: Please, just make a text version. Accessibility, copyability, usability all improves

Comment: I literally cannot read this.

Comment: Reading from the image might have worked with the first version of the image. The text in the current, smaller image is too blurry. Blowing it up to fullscreen will not help at all. (But thanks for providing the clues as text.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer (6,6) is

> ARCTIC CIRCLE

Because each clue represents a geographic location (region)

> within the Arctic Circle (As noted in the title, the regions add together to form this region)

Solved grid:

> [image: solved grid]

Across

2 The Big Dipper is so beautiful at night.

> ALASKA (state flag) . It (like the rest) is within the Arctic Circle.
>  [image: AK flag]

6 Why is that man killing a demon!?

> Flag of ARKHANGELSK.
>  [image: A flag]

8 That lion is posing with a sword.

> Flag of KRASNOYARSK. Looks like a shovel and scythe.
>  [image: K flag]

10 A fox just found some gold.

> Flag of NORTHWEST TERRITORIES. A fox with some gold.
>   [image: NT flag]

12 Russia but surrounded but yellow.

> Flag of CHUKOTKA has a yellow circle around Russia's flag.
>  [image: C flag]

Down

[Word 9] but different

> YAMALO-NENETS AO, another AO in Russia similar to 9 (NENETS AO)

3 That dog is shy.

> YUKON flag has a shy looking dog
>  [image: Y flag]

4 Have you ever heard of an inuksuk?

> My in to the puzzle. Flag of NUNAVUT has one.
>  [image: N flag]

5 I see an aurora.

> Flag of MURMANSK
>  [image: M flag]

7 Solve the puzzle of Poland.

> Clever.  GREENLAND has a flag composed of bits of Poland's flag
>  [image: G flag]
>  [image: P flag]

9. 8 fish tails with some if you look closer.

> Flag of NENETS AO in Russia
>  [image: N flag]

11 Snowy summer.

> YAKUTIA flag has a 'snow white sun'.
>  [image: Y flag]

Comment: You got the final answer right, but you got two wrong in the crossword

Comment: @IsaacRoanSison Okay I think I have it now

Comment: Ha, nice. But I think 8 isn't a good fit, both geographically and tool-wise. Perhaps [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finland) might be better?